# How to check if a <td> element has got colspan attribute in Angular+Protractor e2e testing with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

How to check if a  element has got colspan attribute in Angular+Protractor e2e testing with typescript

i tried the following, but doesnt seems to be working

`const colspan = await cols[0].getAttribute('colspan');`

Comment: `.getAttribute('colspan')` is the right way, probably `cols[0]` points to wrong element (not the one you think)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried switching the way you locate the element?
I don't know how you declared `cols` but I assume you could do something like this:

`const colspan = await cols.get(0).getAttribute('colspan');`

Also share the html element and what error it throws you so we can help you better